# Laravel return custom api resource

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-api

I am currently creating an API to display the count of documents by types.

This is my `type` table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | bcd |
| 3 | efd |

And this is my `documents` tables:

| id | document_name | type_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1 |
| 2 | bcd | 2 |
| 3 | efd | 3 |

I want to return my `Resource` like this:

```
'title' => 'Title',
'types' => [
    [
        'label' => 'abc',
        'total' => 1
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'bcd',
        'total' => 2
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'efd',
        'total' => 3
    ]
]
```

How can I create a custom resource with looping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a resource that works for a single object, then use resource collection for the types to loop over the documents.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections